Gilab bridge job error - Failed(job would create infinite looping pipelines)
Below is the pipeline flow between different systems

As shown in the picture - after highlighted system, gitlab pipelines stops and throws error as bridge job error - Failed(job would create infinite looping pipelines)
How to resolve the issue. Is it gitlab behaviour or do we have workaround?

It is probable that one of your pipelines has a child pipeline that refers to one of the pipelines in the list, or the trigger for one of the pipelines is another of the pipelines. Somehow, you have created a circular dependency.

@JamesSheils: seems line gitlab by default retricting CYCLICAL_TRIGGERED_PIPELINES. i would like to know if there is an option to disable this option
